# Check a string to see if 2 letters are found next to each other in the string

Tags: java

I need to figure out how to determine true or false if 2 specific letters in a string are right next to each other.

For example: In AplusRunner the `System.out.println(AB.check("frog","f","g"));` should return false because the letters "f" and "g" are not right next to each other.

`System.out.println(AB.check("chicken","c","k"));` should return true since "c" and "k" are right next to each other.

All I need help with is how to determine if a string contains two letters right next to each other or not. Thanks

```
public class AB
{
    public static boolean check( String s, String a, String b)   
    {
   
    }
}
```

```
public class AplusRunner
{
    public static void main( String args[] )
    {


        System.out.println( AB.check( "chicken", "a", "b" ) );
        System.out.println( AB.check( "frog", "f", "g" ) );
        System.out.println( AB.check( "chicken ", "c", "k" ) );
        System.out.println( AB.check( "apluscompsci ", "a", "s" ) );
        System.out.println( AB.check( "apluscompsci ", "a", "p" ) );
        System.out.println( AB.check( "apluscompsci ", "s", "c" ) );
        System.out.println( AB.check( "apluscompsci ", "c", "p" ) );
            
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't you just concatenate the two letters and see if the string contains that concatenation, e.g. `"chicken".contains("ck")`? You can concatenate them the other way round as well if you need to check both options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `String#contains` here:

```
public static boolean check(String s, String a, String b) {
    return s.contains(a + b)
}
```

Comment: This will have strange behaviour when `a` or `b` is a regex special character like `[` or `.`. I'd get rid of `matches` and just suggest `contains`

Comment: @Clashsoft Fair point, but under the OP's assumptions, only lettere would be inputs, but I agree with you.